# Mule MEL Date Time Format

Tags: mule, mel

I am trying to output data in `DD-MON-YY(22-OCT-15)` format to insert into an Oracle DB. I used the MEL expression `server.dateTime.format("dd-MMM-yy")`. This outputs data as `22-Oct-15`.   See fragment below.

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[if ( flowVars.collection_opening_date == null){
    flowVars.collection_opening_date = server.dateTime.format("dd-MMM-yy");
}]]></expression-component>
```

There is no error from this snippet.  `server.dateTime.format("dd-MMM-yy")` outputs as `22-Oct-15` and **my desired format is `22-OCT-15`**. How can I get my desired format?

Comment: Can you explain your desired behaviour more please?  And share more about what problem/error is ocurring.

Comment: There is no error server.dateTime.format("dd-MMM-yy") outputs as 22-Oct-15 and my desired format is 22-OCT-15. Is it possible via

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uppercase it like so: `server.dateTime.format("dd-MMM-yy").toUpperCase().`

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the quick response. Worked like a charm.